# Descartes Modeling Language, overview?

Tags: modeling, descartes

Descartes Modeling Language vs. Palladio Component Model

I really have to know what especially the first one (DML) IS and what you can do with it.
Pretty hard to google information about this stuff..
I found some papers about is with scholar.google.com but those are super technical. Would be awesome if someone could give me a quick overview T.T

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, asking for external resources is considered off-topic here: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." ([help/on-topic])

Comment: I am not asking for external resources. I can google myself. I want to talk to someone that knows what DML related stuff is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descartes Modeling Language is an architectural modeling language that enables designers to build models that can be used to do performance predictions and system adaptations at runtime. Its distinctive characteristic when compared to Palladio Component Model (PCM) is that it is mainly intended to be used at runtime to enable self-adaptation (not at design time as PCM).

The central idea is summarized here: "DML is designed to serve as a basis for self-aware resource management1 [1, 2] during operation ensuring that system quality-of-service requirements are continuously satisfied while infrastructure resources are utilized as efficiently as possible."

I guess that a good start point is this "tutorial": http://opus.bibliothek.uni-wuerzburg.de/files/10488/DML-TechReport-1.0.pdf

Best regards,

Fábio